# asset imageURL passed as string to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, url, alassetslibrary

This is a simplified version of an app I have that gets an image url from the iPhone/iPad image library, stores the string for that URL in core-data and later displays it in another controller.  What I think is the correct URl gets stored in core-data but does not display when retrieved later.

To try and troubleshoot, I have an app that gets a picture from the iPhone/iPad image library and displays it on the screen.  I then press a button to segue to a second view controller and display it again.  It does not appear on the second view controller.  I am displaying it in the first scene with the same method I use in the second controller just to show that the method works give the correct URL.  I am passing the URL as a string between the controllers to simulate the URL being stored in core-data so passing it as a NSURL isn't an option for this sample.

First view controller.h and .m files

```
//
//  patViewController.h
//  pictureAssetTest
//
//  Created by Chip Cox on 8/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Home. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CCExtras.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface patViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@end



//
//  patViewController.m
//  pictureAssetTest
//
//  Created by Chip Cox on 8/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Home. All rights reserved.
//

#import "patViewController.h"
#import "patSecondVC.h"

@interface patViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageControl;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSURL *imageURL;
@end

@implementation patViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)selectPictureFromLibrary:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self startPhotoLibraryFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.imageURL=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    CCLog(@"Image =%@",[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]);

    [self displayImageFromURL:self.imageURL];
}

- (void) displayImageFromURL:(NSURL*)urlIn
{
    ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

    switch(status){
        case ALAuthorizationStatusDenied: {
            CCLog(@"not authorized");
            break;
        }
        case ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted: {
            CCLog(@"Restricted");
            break;
        }
        case ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
            CCLog(@"Undetermined");
            break;
        }
        case ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized: {
            CCLog(@"Authorized");
            CCLog(@"urlIn=%@",urlIn.pathComponents);
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            __block UIImage *returnValue = nil;
            [library assetForURL:urlIn resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                returnValue = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.imageControl setImage:returnValue];
                    [self.imageControl setNeedsDisplay];
                });
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
            }];
            break;
        }
        default: {
            CCLog(@"Unknown hit default");
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) startPhotoLibraryFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or
    // movie capture, if both are available:
    cameraUI.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[patSecondVC class]]) {
        CCLog(@"Preparing for segue to %@",segue.destinationViewController);
        patSecondVC *dvc=segue.destinationViewController;
        dvc.transferURL=self.imageURL.absoluteString;
    } else {
        CCLog(@"Preparing to segue to unknown destination view controller %@",segue.destinationViewController);
    }
}

@end
```

The following code is the second view controller .h and .m files.

```
//
//  patSecondVC.h
//  pictureAssetTest
//
//  Created by Chip Cox on 8/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Home. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
#import "CCExtras.h"

@interface patSecondVC : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *transferURL;
@end



//
//  patSecondVC.m
//  pictureAssetTest
//
//  Created by Chip Cox on 8/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Home. All rights reserved.
//

#import "patSecondVC.h"

@interface patSecondVC ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageControl;

@end

@implementation patSecondVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    CCLog(@"photo url=%@",self.transferURL);
    [self displayImageFromURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.transferURL]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) displayImageFromURL:(NSURL*)urlIn
{
    ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

    switch(status){
        case ALAuthorizationStatusDenied: {
            CCLog(@"not authorized");
            break;
        }
        case ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted: {
            CCLog(@"Restricted");
            break;
        }
        case ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
            CCLog(@"Undetermined");
            break;
        }
        case ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized: {
            CCLog(@"Authorized");
            CCLog(@"urlIn=%@",urlIn.pathComponents);
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            __block UIImage *returnValue = nil;
            [library assetForURL:urlIn resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                returnValue = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.imageControl setImage:returnValue];
                    [self.imageControl setNeedsDisplay];
                });
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
            }];
            break;
        }
        default: {
            CCLog(@"Unknown hit default");
            break;
        }

    }

}
@end
```

Thanks

Added log output

```
2014-08-11 17:05:37.194 pictureAssetTest[2544:60b] <-[patViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:] - 45> Image =assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=5E208B2D-65CC-4F46-8F22-DD2E8006AF1B&ext=PNG
2014-08-11 17:05:37.195 pictureAssetTest[2544:60b] <-[patViewController displayImageFromURL:] - 68> Authorized
2014-08-11 17:05:37.196 pictureAssetTest[2544:60b] <-[patViewController displayImageFromURL:] - 69> urlIn=(
    "/",
    "asset.PNG"
)
2014-08-11 17:05:39.149 pictureAssetTest[2544:60b] <-[patViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] - 116> Preparing for segue to <patSecondVC: 0xa49c610>
2014-08-11 17:05:39.150 pictureAssetTest[2544:60b] <-[patSecondVC viewDidLoad] - 31> photo url=assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=5E208B2D-65CC-4F46-8F22-DD2E8006AF1B&ext=PNG
2014-08-11 17:05:39.151 pictureAssetTest[2544:60b] <-[patSecondVC displayImageFromURL:] - 59> Authorized
2014-08-11 17:05:39.151 pictureAssetTest[2544:60b] <-[patSecondVC displayImageFromURL:] - 60> urlIn=(
    "/",
    "assets-library:",
    asset,
    "asset.PNG?id=5E208B2D-65CC-4F46-8F22-DD2E8006AF1B&ext=PNG"
)
```

Comment: in prepareForSegue, is dvc.transferURL nil by any chance? what do you see in the output of     CCLog(@"photo url=%@",self.transferURL);
 in the second controller?

Comment: Added log output as requested.  Nope, it's not nil. In prepare for segue, I've tried setting with the reference url in which case I get the /asset.PNG output, and the absolutepath shown in the example.  Same results both ways.

Comment: in the second VC, can you make a change to make the call on main thread only of its NOT already on the main thread? is UIImageView *imageControl IBOutlet connected in storyboard? can you confirm that at this line  is not nil:                     [self.imageControl setImage:returnValue];
also try setting an image from the bundle at this line as well

Comment: I'm guessing you wanted to check self.imageControl in the second scene.  I put in a display of it's description there and got 2014-08-11 17:44:22.947 pictureAssetTest[2842:60b] <__35-[patSecondVC displayImageFromURL:]_block_invoke_2 - 67> self.imageControl=<UIImageView: 0xa4a21b0; frame = (20 20; 728 554); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa4b7100>>   so it's not nil.  I confess I'm pretty new to objective C.  I know I can use [NSThread isMainThread] to determine whether I'm in the main thread.  I'm just not sure how to use it in the code, please advise.

Comment: are you able to set a local image to this? instead of from the url .. something like [self.imageControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"localimage.png"]];

Comment: yes, I created an imageset and pulled up an image from there in the secondscene right between the setImage and the needsdisplay lines.  It was displayed properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59138/discussion-between-hackerinheels-and-turboc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second vc change the call to

```
[self displayImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.transferURL]];
```

That should fix it!

Comment: but imageURL is a NSURL not NSString.  I can't store a NSURL in coredata.  Right?  So i have to convert the NSURL to a string and then back to a NSURL in the destination viewcontroller.

Comment: getting an dump NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2b1df0' on the call above.  Does this need to be a c'string instead of a NSString passed to URLWithString?  url is assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=13A3DD08-3410-4181-8A20-621A53ABBF59&ext=JPG

Comment: Where is it crashing?

Comment: got it, I still had the change to load transferURL with the NSURL instead of NSURL.absolutePath.  I changed it back and it works.  Thanks